# tt_news: wrap around image including caption?

Tags: typo3, tt-news

I am trying to get a wrapper element around an image including its caption in the single view in tt_news for Typo3 6.1. How would I do that?
So far I only figured out how to do that for either all images

> plugin.tt_news.displaySingle.imageWrapIfAny = ...

or the caption itself

> plugin.tt_news.displaySingle.caption_stdWrap.dataWrap = ...

. But I have no clue how to create a wrapper for each single image including its caption...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't googled enough before asking. Meanwhile I found the solution: [link](http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-german/2009-May/058826.html)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old, but as a follow-up that works in TYPO3 6.x you can use:

```
displaySingle.image.wrap = <div class="news-img">|
displaySingle.caption_stdWrap >
displaySingle.caption_stdWrap.wrap = <p class="news-single-imgcaption">|</p></div>
```

So each image and caption gets wrapped by `<div class="news-img">...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

The following HTML will be provided by the below TS:

```
<div class="newsImage">
    <div class="imageHolder">
        <img />
    </div>
    <div class="captionHolder">
        Caption
    </div>
</div>
```

TypoScript:

```
displaySingle {

    imageWrapIfAny = <div class="newsImage">|</div>

    image {
        file.maxW >
        file.maxH >
        file.width = 220
        stdWrap.wrap = <div class="imageHolder">|</div>
        altText.field = imagealttext
    }

    caption_stdWrap >
    caption_stdWrap.wrap = <div class="captionHolder">|</div>
}
```